# how to manipulate pandas DataFrame using query or connect on current python server

Tags: python, pandas

I want to NON-EQUI merge two DataFrame.
But I found that pandas DataFrame does not support non-equi join.

So I want to use query for join two DataFrame

How can I manipulate pandas DataFrame using Query

Like,
df = pd.DataFrame({"a":[1, 2, 3]})

SELECT a FROM df;

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Pandas equivalent of SQL non-equi JOIN](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50573457/pandas-equivalent-of-sql-non-equi-join)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install pandasql

[pandasql](https://pypi.org/project/pandasql/)

```
from pandasql import sqldf, load_meat
pysqldf = lambda q: sqldf(q, globals())
meat = load_meat()
print(pysqldf("SELECT * FROM meat LIMIT 10;").head())
```